# Why we use property in c# class?

Tags: c#, .net

I have been coding last few months. Perhaps 7 months and I became flexible with basic things like , string manipulation, I/O , types , variables and so on....

In my project I used global variables always and I saw people uses  property and stays away from global variables..

I don't see a point to use property get;set;

In my project I have a method executor and methods are been selected depending upon param and method type which I provide...

I read the data in to global var and then do execution by switch case ....I have scopes so I don't face any issue of variable override or any sort of issue like that..

But I see established projects has lots of property usage.  Why they use?  Also is the property value set is available in whole class that holds property ?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. In it's current form this question is too broad for the Q+A format of this site. Please read through the help center, specifically [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) It sounds like you are new to "object oriented" programming so suggest you read some articles/books around the topic to give yourself a better understanding.

Comment: It's difficult to offer general advice here. If you're writing small, relatively self-contained programs, there may not be much benefit to be realised yet; I don't think the linked dupe is particularly good for answering what you've asked here but agree with Chris that it's too broad as it currently stands.

Answer (score 0):

In fact we use classes to realize business entities and all the materials we have are for this target; properties are same as **characteristics of an object**.
In your opinion, you violate the principles of the **Clean Code** and **OOP**
I think you should focus more on OOP.